# How to deploy multiple (java web apps) war files in tomacat?

Tags: java, jsp, war

We have one main domain, from that we can able to create unlimited jsp sites (Addon domains)... my question is? i want to deploy different war file for that jsp sites... i have shared hosting, private jvm, cpanel.... Plz help me!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly,  you have different domains pointing to the same server and you want tomcat to serve a different default Web app for each domain. You caan do that by editing the server. xml file. See the tomcat docs for detsils:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html